# Error when installing google-chrome-stable on python image in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, dockerfile

I wanted to install google-chrome-stable on pyton image in docker, but I got the following error:

```
[7/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable:
#11 1.250 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
#11 1.275 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
#11 1.279 Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
#11 3.055 Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [291 kB]
#11 3.173 Fetched 408 kB in 2s (186 kB/s)
#11 3.173 Reading package lists...
#11 3.850 Reading package lists...
#11 4.502 Building dependency tree...
#11 4.644 Reading state information...
#11 4.751 E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable]: exit code: 100
```

My dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /test
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

ADD . /app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY . /test
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8080", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the instructions [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome) you need to add the chrome repo. So changing your dockerfile to something like the following works:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /test
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Thanks for your fix. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @caspii, if you give more info someone might be able to help

Comment: it works for me on x86_64 but it does not work on Aarch64. I can't understand the reason.

Comment: This is not working for me now.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error code when running a docker image like this (I already added the chrome repo) on **Macbook M1**.
If you face the same problem, modify the first line in Dockerfile by:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8
```

Source: https://github.com/joyzoursky/docker-python-chromedriver/issues/30